# Use a filter for wp_robots to block CPT/feed/

Tags: functions, feed, robots.txt

We have a CPT (with base slug `templates`) that somehow included in every single post's head a link to `/templates/post/feed/`.

I've removed this link to the feed from the head, but want to block robots from the feed also.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771322/667903), I can adapt code like:

```
add_filter( 'wp_robots', function( $robots ) {
  if ( is_singular( 'templates' ) ) {
    $robots['noindex']  = true;
    $robots['nofollow'] = true;
  }

  return $robots;
} );
```

but don't know how to include [is_feed()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_feed/) into this code.

Would I use something like `if ( is_singular( 'templates' ) && is_feed( 'templates' ) )` ?

Help appreciated.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, I could somehow add the following to `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /templates/*/feed
```

but do not know the function/hook to do this. We're using `Yoast SEO`.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoast SEO has [a robots.txt editor](https://yoast.com/features/file-editor-robots-txt/) that worked well.

[image]

This solved our problem.